# Multitenancy in micronaut java

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, multi-tenant, micronaut

If I hit the post method I got the error `Internal Server Error: No GORM implementations configured. Ensure GORM has been initialized correctly`
In MultiTenantResolver, resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier is use to identify the tenantId from header which passed during the request get hit, I implemented the multitenancy code properly but my database is not changing while tenantid is in header

```
import grails.gorm.multitenancy.CurrentTenant
import grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import java.net.http.HttpResponse

@Controller("/api")
@CurrentTenant
class DummyController {
    @Inject
    private Accountserviceimpl accountserviceimpl;
    @Inject
    private MultiTenantResolver multiTenantResolver;
    @Post("/accounts")
    public HttpResponse<Account> createAccounts(@Body Account account){
        String tenantId = multiTenantResolver.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier();
        Account account1;
        Tenants.withId(tenantId){
            account1 = accountserviceimpl.saveAccount(account);
        }
        return io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse.created(account1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.